# Rails I18n returns hash with nil as key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I am using Rails with `rails-i18n` gem for translation

The gem is returning a hash with nil as the key.

```
2.0.0-p481 :003 > I18n.t('term.market')
 => {:secondary=>"Secondary Market", :primary=>"Primary Market", nil=>"Market"}
```

This is very odd behaviour, as the gem used to return "Market"

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Currently have in the Gemfile: `gem 'rails',              '~>4.1.7'`

Comment: Okay. i18n is included in Rails base install since version 2.2 (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), so you don't need to install it as a gem. You should remove rails-i18n gem from the Gemfile and bundle install. I don't know if this solves the problem but to double install i18n can't be a good thing.